# How to manage mirophone access if another app is using in in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, microphone

I am working on an app that has a speech recognition and normal voice recording functions. The problem is that neither of those is able to handle the case where microphone is busy.

I saw another similar question but it didn't have any clear answers in it.

I use the flutter_sound recorder for normal recordings and it ends up generating an empty unusable sound file in the end. While for speech recognition I use the vosk_flutter package which simply throws an uncatchable error.

Below is my code for speech recognition:

```
    try {
      _speechService = await _vosk.initSpeechService(_recognizer);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      await _speechService?.dispose();
      _speechService = await _vosk.initSpeechService(_recognizer);
    }
    if (onPartial != null) {
      _speechService?.onPartial().forEach(onPartial);
    } else {
      _speechService?.onPartial().drain();
    }
    if (onResult != null) {
      _speechService?.onResult().forEach(onResult);
    } else {
      _speechService?.onResult().drain();
    }
    try {
      await _speechService?.start();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
```

I tried wrapping everything with try-catch blocks, but the errors still persisted.
I also noticed that using the speech_to_text package that also provides the speech recognition functionality is able to "take" the mic to itself. I tested it using the android voice recorder app, activating the speech_to_text package's service would stop the other app's mic and start using it. This proves that there is at least some way to do this.